# CSES "Moving Robots": How can we solve this expected value problem?

Tags: expected-value, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve the following problem: Given a 8x8 board where each square has one robot on it, define a move as follows: every robot moves either up, down, left, or right (each with an equal probability), such that they do not move outside of the board and such that multiple robots are allowed on each square. After K moves (1 <= K <= 100), find the expected number of **empty** squares. (For reference, [this is the exact problem](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1726)).

My idea to solve this was Dynamic Programming; let `prob[k][r][c]` = P(there is at least one robot on the square in row r and column c after exactly k moves). Our base case is prob[0][1..8][1..8] = 1, since each square starts out with one robot. Then, I tested having `prob[k+1][r_f][c_f] = sum of prob[k][all r, c that are one move away from the current square] / [number of valid moves from r, c]` as the transitions, but it turns out that was wrong.

Right now, I don't know how to proceed on this problem, so could someone explain a solution to it? Is my approach somewhat correct, or am I making some basic mistake in my logic?

Comment: Your approach is fine, but you can’t just sum those probabilities, because that  assumes that from each neighboring square they are certain to go to the square you are focusing on, and that is not the case  … so, you need to multiply each of those probabilities by the probability of actually moving to your square. This will of course be one in four for all squates, except for the corner squares (one in two) and the side-but-not-corner squares (one in three)

Comment: Oops! I actually did do that in my original solution - I forgot to put it in this question. The solution did not work, however.

Comment: Instead of using the probability of there being at least one robot in a square, how about using the expected number of robots in that square?

Comment: Your approach will not work as it stands.  The probability that any robots are at $(r,c)$ at time $t$ depends not only on *whether* there are robots at $(r\pm 1, c\pm 1)$ at time $t-1$, but also on *how many* there are.  Your DP solution is not tracking the number of robots in each square.

Comment: Because the robots move independently, can you see how to express the answer in terms of the transition probabilities between each pair of squares (I.e. the probability of going from $(r,c)$ to $(r’,c’)$ in $K$ steps)? Those probabilities can certainly be found by dynamic programming.

Comment: Or maybe have a probability distribution for each of the 64 robots? That is: for each robot, what is the probability it is in a certain square after k moves? If you do this for all robots, you can calculate, for each square, the probability no robot is in it after k moves. …. though I am not sure you can get expected number of empty squares easily from that …

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is right:

The expected number of empty squares (after k steps) is the sum of the contribution of square 1 to be empty (which is 1) times the probability of square 1 to be empty (after k steps), plus the contribution of square 2 to be empty (which is 1) times the probability of square 2 to be empty (after k steps), etc. ... and so it is just the sum of the probabilities of each square to be empty (after k steps).

OK, so now you have to find the probability that a specific square is empty after k steps.  My method would be to just keep track of all 64 robots and for each robot, figure out probability that it is in a certain square after k moves. And that can easily be done iteratively: you know where the robot is after 0 steps, and if you know the probability distribution after k-1 steps, you can easily compute the probability distribution for k steps.

Finally, if you do this for all robots, you can calculate, for each square, the probability no robot is in it after k moves.

You might obtain some speed-up by exploiting the symmetry of the board.